# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified. Tomcat 9 Eclipse Java EE Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, eclipse, tomcat

My ubuntu version is `18.04`

My eclipse version is `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers 2018-09 (4.9.0)`

[image: Eclipse Version]

Tomcat version is `9.0.13`

[image: Tomcat Version]

I installed tomcat from this tutorial:
[www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804)

Problem is the same as at the title. Eclipse does not recognize tomcat

I tried those options:

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/
sudo chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/
```

I tried setup tomcat to `~/bin/tomcat` and I gave same permissions. Nothing has changed.

Still got the `Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.` error.
[image: Tomcat include error]

I tried already a few different solutions but none of all works. I search a lot but I can't solve the problem so I opened the title.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and Tomcat 9, to fix it run this command:

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /your_installation_forder/tomcat